# CNAME in Heroku - what to use for alias?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, dns

I am trying to use a custom domain in Heroku, but the instructions are not working for me.

Heroku instructions are at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

I changed CNAME at my host to several things, because the instructions in Heroku are really unclear.

For CNAME alias, I tried several things:

1. www.example.com
2. example.com
3. www
4. proxy.heroku.com

And for my address, they all point to the same thing: [www.morning-harbor.herokuapp.com](http://morning-harbor.herokuapp.com)

I use moniker.com's DNS servers. However, when I try on the command line

```
host www.example.com
```

It points me to my old virtual server IP address, not Heroku or moniker.com

Which one is the right CNAME alias to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a CNAME FROM www TO morning-harbor.herokuapp.com

you cant have a CNAME for apex records (yourdomain.com)

Comment: Actually this turned out to be the wrong answer. The right answer is 'www'.